# Angular / Ionic Framework - trying to bind to an object within *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using an external API to retrieve fields for a form in an Ionic app that I'm developing. I then collecting the information from this form in order to create a new object which will be sent to the API in order to make a record.

One of the groups of fields (called methods) can be variable in the number of entries, so I have been able to display the fields using an *ngFor= directive. However I'm having an issue trying to collect the information from these. Here is my code:

From new-trip.html:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Justification</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="newTrip.justification">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let tripFieldJustification of tripFieldJustifications" value="{{tripFieldJustification.id}}">{{ tripFieldJustification.description }}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>


<ion-item-divider color="light">Travel Time</ion-item-divider>
<ion-item *ngFor="let tripFieldMethod of tripFieldMethods">
  <ion-label floating>Hours travelled by {{ tripFieldMethod.method }} {{ tripFieldMethod.id }}</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" type="number" [(ngModel)]="newTripHours[tripFieldMethod.id]" value="0"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

From the corresponding new-trip.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-trip',
  templateUrl: 'new-trip.html'
})
export class NewTripPage {
  logOut: any;
  tripFields: any;
  tripFieldMethods: any = [];
  tripFieldGenerals: any = [];
  tripFieldPurposes: any = [];
  tripFieldJustifications: any = [];
  postAddType: any;
  postPreviousPage: any;
  newTrip: any = {};
  newTripHours: any = {};
  methods: any;
  currentYear: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public logOutService: LogOutService, public travelTrackerService: TravelTrackerService, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.logOut = logOutService;
    this.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    this.postAddType = navParams.get('addType');
    this.postPreviousPage = navParams.get('previousPage');
    travelTrackerService.getTripFields().then((response) => {
      this.tripFields = response;
      this.tripFieldMethods = this.tripFields['method'];
      this.tripFieldGenerals = this.tripFields['general'];
      this.tripFieldPurposes = this.tripFields['purpose'];
      this.tripFieldJustifications = this.tripFields['justification'];
    });
  }
```

In the code below, I have no problem getting the justification property to bind to newTrip.justification. However I can't get the 'method' input fields to bind to any objects, I keep getting the following error:

```
NewTripPage.html:153 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NewTripPage.html:153)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13844)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
```

I understand that this problem is related to an array. How would I be able to get these dynamically changing fields to bind to an object?

I am very new to Angular, if anybody would be able to help I would very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are right the problem is in the array.
You have to write your array like this.

```
private partnerArray: Array<{
  id: number;
  imageUrl: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}> = [];
```

and fill this array like this.

```
  this.partnerArray.push({
      id: query[i].id,
      imageUrl: "data:image/*;base64," + query[i].image_small,
      name: query[i].name == false ? "N/A" : query[i].name,
      email: query[i].email == false ? "N/A" : query[i].email
    });
```

That's it in ts file. Now you can access it in `.html` file like this.

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Justification</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="newTrip.justification">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let partner of partnerArray" value="{{partner.id}}">{{ partner.name }}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

Well That's it.
Hope it will help you